# Login page with multiple forms?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Can anyone please explain about Login page that contains multiple forms.  I mean On submitting some details it should goto some other page there we have to enter some other details after that it should goto to final page there other  details of the form are  entered and finally all the details are stored in the database?  We daily saw so many Sites that contain this type of Login forms . Can you please explain where the data of first form is stored? and how this works with an example?

Comment: I'd guess it is stored somewhere in a session or in RAM.

Comment: Maybe you mean _Registration Page_? Usually _Login Page_ needs just two fields: Login (Username) and Password.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data from the first two login forms in the Session data, before finally saving it on the last page. Either that or each login page stores the data in the DB, but posts the ID of the row to the next form in order to update the same entry each time.

A bit more information on what you're trying to achieve might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from the first form to a dynamic Server page(eg PHP), there u can actually save the data in variables and can set them in hidden fields and can further resubmit the form with these hidden elements to the final target server page.

```
<input type="hidden" value="xxx">
```

xxx = value from the previously submitted form

Answer (score 0):

You mean Submitting page or clicking Next?

Because each form has single Submit action where it transfers the data to server page and the data gets stored. So , when you click Next, the data are stored simple in a variable and the next page is loaded. The variable can be Session or simple variable. And finally when you click submit in final page, the data are submitted.

Hope it clears your doubt.